# how to preserve array outside of method in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, release

After a ASIFormDataRequest , i create a temporary NSMutableArray *resultArray from the JSON then add it to a defined NSMutablearray *myData

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    myData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //request that calls gotInfo method
}

-(void)gotInfo:(ASIFormDataRequest *)request{
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    NSMutableArray *resultArray = [responseString yajl_JSON];
    [myData addObject:resultArray];
}

-(IBAction)doSomethingWithData:(id)sender{
    //something with myData
}
```

but when i try to call myData from outside of the gotInfo: method, i get bad access errors and when i inspect myData outside of the method, it shows a kern_protection_failure.  So i'm guessing that outside of the method, the resultArray is obviously released, but it's also released from myData since the object inside myData is sharing the same memory location?
I also tried

```
-(void)gotInfo:(ASIFormDataRequest *)request{
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    [myData addObject:[responseString yajl_JSON]];
}
```

How do I preserve myData??

in my header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ASIFormDataRequest;

@interface EventsTableController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource>{
    NSMutableArray *myData;
}
-(void)gotInfo:(ASIFormDataRequest *)request;
```

**UPDATE:**

so in the gbd, the myData is allocated as 0x5e96560 so i did

```
po 0x5e96560
```

and then i get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS with the reason being KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at address: 0x00000009

but if i do

```
po [[0x5e96560 objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"key"]
```

then i get the value! whyyyyyy?

Comment: may you post the code where you initialize `myData`?

Comment: @Saphrosit: I updated my post with the code

Comment: Since you are adding the object [responseString yajl_JSON] to your array myData, the array myData increases the retain count on the object by 1, so it probably has to deal with the method yajl_JSON. Are you sure it's returning an NSMutableArray pointer?

Comment: yes, the responseString comes from json_encode($phpArray)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *myData
```

and create the object

```
self.myData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

and

```
// and i assume your resultArray is a mature NSMutableArray object
[self.myData addObject:resultArray];
```

> The best way of using copy I can think of, is to always set NSString properties to "copy" instead of retain. That way you get more accurate readings from the Leaks instrument if you mess up and forget to release a string an object is holding onto. Other uses of copy need to be more carefully thought out.

NOTE : You are responsible to release myData after no use of that variable.

Comment: I tried your code but still same kern failure.  I'll double check to make sure there is nothing wrong with the resultArray

Comment: Enable **NSDebugEnabled**
  **NSZombieEnabled**
 **MallocStackLogging**
  **MallocStackLoggingNoCompact**   see http://42games.net/quick-note-on-setting-nszombieenabled-environment-variable-in-xcode-4/   *_Which will you more detail about the error_* then we can see what is the exact problem ?  while your program is running, open a terminal, do a
**ps -ax**
to find the pid of your process, then type
**leaks (pid)**

to get some information about memory leaks you have going.

Comment: do i type the ps-ax and leaks(pid) in the gdb?

Comment: how do i access the terminal? (sorry i'm a newb)

Comment: i checked the leaks with leaks pid|more and apparently i have 54... but i don't think memory leaks would contribute to kern failure... i'll try to fix the leaks and see if anything changes

Comment: Since you've specified `myData` with `retain`, then `self.myData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` will cause a double-retain. Bad mojo.

Comment: i added the @property and @synthesize again but using copy, and did `myData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` and i can now see the array! although, i'm not sure why i need the setter/getters though...

Answer (score 0):

You dont really have any way to correctly access myData as you declare it as a member inside of EventsTableController, but you dont set the @property for it, and do not synthesize it either. By synthesizing it in your EventsTableController.m file you are telling xcode to generate the getter/setters you need to correctly touch myData, which is where your program seems to be failing. If you do this, this should solve your problem.

-Karoly

Comment: I thought setters/getters used only if an instance of my EventsTableController was created from another class.  I added `@property(nonatomic,copy) NSMutableArray *myData` and added the synthesize but i still get the kern protection failure

Comment: @Andrew Park: Hmm, where are you initializing myData? That could be it, though that usually generates an EXC_BAD_ACCESS, I haven't really seen a kern protection failure.

Comment: You don't need any getters and setters for myData at all, unless you need another class to access that object.

Comment: I initialized it in the viewDidLoad, i updated my post with more code

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't see it mentioned where he was doing all of the accessing, etc, so I figured I would put it in. At this point I'm out of ideas as to what it could be.

Comment: @Andrew Park did you try my code, you should **retain** the myData rather than **copy**. I describe the reason as well

Answer (score 0):

Except for the different name of your ivar (`mienVar` vs. `myVar`), I don't see a problem. Some other code must be releasing your ivar, or you are accessing it **before** `viewDidLoad` has the opportunity to actually create the array (I bet it is the latter).

I think you should put the code in `viewDidLoad` in your initialization method instead. Don't forget to release the array in `dealloc`.

You could, of course, also write your own `myData` getter method, doing lazy initialization, instead of creating it in the init method:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) myData
{
    if (!myData)
        myData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return myData;
}
```

**Note that now, you should access** `self.myData` **if you want to use it.**

Comment: I updated my code because i realized the flow of events wasn't clear.  So the gotInfo: method runs right after the viewDidLoad and i put a breakpoint at the end of the method, and see the objects in myData.  Then I set a button with an IBAction which needs myData, but when I put the breakpoint in the IBAction, but now there is the kern failure

Comment: It is hard to tell, without access to the rest of your code, which other code could invalidate your array, sorry.

Comment: I understand, just one question.  after the addObject, even if the temporary array is released, myData SHOULD still retain it?

Comment: It should, unless it is "over-released", i.e. released twice.

Comment: when you put the breakpoint in the IBAction, there is the kern failure. Does it tell more about that error in console. are you sure you gave the right action reference to your button?

Comment: Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at address: 0x00000008
0x01dd409b in objc_msgSend ()
The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
GDB has restored the context to what it was before the call.
To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal off"
Evaluation of the expression containing the function (_NSPrintForDebugger) will be abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

I think the NSString yajl_JSON category can return an array or a dictionary - you might need to inspect the type of the result array on the line below as it may be an NSDictionary:

NSMutableArray *resultArray = [responseString yajl_JSON];

IF you are treating it as an array when its a dictionary that might be causing your problems.

(relevant code from the NSObject+YAJL category below)

```
YAJLDocument *document = [[YAJLDocument alloc] initWithData:data parserOptions:options error:error];
id root = [document.root retain];
[document release];
return [root autorelease];
```

(and in YAJLDocument object)

```
@interface YAJLDocument : NSObject <YAJLParserDelegate> {
(id root_; // NSArray or NSDictionary
```

Comment: i tried saving the `[responseString yajl_JSON]` as NSMutableArray and NSMutableDictionary but both don't work.  Such a frustrating bug